# Microsoft Monitoring Agent's Perfmon.dll crashing IIS Web Application Pool while Using Log4Net - 2.0.9.0 or later

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, log4net, scom

I'm using Log4Net as a logging service in my webApp. I've the Micorosoft Monitoring Agent (8.0.10918.0) installed in my machine (Windows Server 2016 DataCenter) using SCOM 2016 (7.2.11719.0).

The IIS Web Application Pool launching the webapp is crashing by the APM Agent in Microsoft Monitoring Agent. This issue has been already discussed in several posts like:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17f589b0-97be-414e-84f7-40703a0c444f/iis-website-is-crashed-by-the-microsoft-monitoring-agent-in-windows-server-2016?forum=scomapm

I've downgraded the Log4Net to 2.0.8.0 which is working fine. All the other version upto the latest version have this issue.

I'm using some other dll's supporting my webApp but this(Log4Net.dll) is the one causing the issue.

Can anyone address what exactly the issue is and what is the root cause for the issue?
Why the latest Log4Net versions above 2.0.8.0 having this issue?
How to solve the issue without disabling the APM Agent, because the Log4Net 2.0.8.0 is working with the same APM Agent?

Comment: The solution is that either log4net authors update it to be compatible with SCOM agent, or Microsoft updates its agent. But neither of those happens here, so I don't think a meaningful answer can be expected.

Comment: I've updated the SCOM version and the issue is solved that way, But I wanna know what is the issue with Log4Net versions. And the SCOM update release notes says that they disable the APM by default, that may not be the right solution. [Release Notes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-rollup-6-for-system-center-2016-operations-manager-39819b20-c3d9-5cf7-1928-59c199b055e6)

Comment: To me “This issue is fixed by disabling the profiler by default and enabling it only when APM is configured” is very different from "release notes says that they disable the APM by default" (unless we speak different English). Anyway, SCOM is not open sourced, and there isn't further information regarding this crash. So, I don't expect any outsider give more insights. Even inside Microsoft, I bet only a small group might know. You'd better open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com to learn more if you like.

Comment: Oh thank you Jesus of heaven!  You @NithishKumar are the only person, on the entire internet... no the entire universe!, that has figured out what I needed to do in my project to solve this issue other than uninstalling Microsoft Monitoring Agent from the server.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to find this root cause. But reference to official document :[APM feature causes a crash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/system-center/scom/apm-feature-causes-iis-application-pool-crash)

Maybe it's similar reason:  Memory allocation conflict.